# Sidebar react-menu-burger doesn't show

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm new to React, and I'm working with an existing project that I have to modify.
I need to add a Sidebar, and following [this tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2018/08/29/how-to-create-sidebar-component-in-react/) I've simply created a component `MySidebar` this way:

```
import React from "react";
import {slide as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'

export class MySidebar extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {


    return (
        <Menu>
            <a id="Project1">Project 1</a>
            <a id="Project2">Project 2</a>
            <a id="Project3">Project 3</a>
        </Menu>
    );
  }
}
```

Then in App.js I have this:

```
render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
         <MySidebar 
      isOpen={true}
      disableCloseOnEsc= {true}
      style={{
          'position': 'fixed',
          'left': '0px',
          'width': '30px',
          'height': '100%',
          'display':'inline-block'
        }}>
        </MySidebar>
          <Particles
            params={{
              "particles": {
                "number": {
                  "value": 100
                },
                "size": {
                  "value": 3
                }
              }
            }}
          </Particles>
          <ProjectSliderComponent projectListId={this.state.projectList}></ProjectSliderComponent>
        </div>
      );
  }
```

`Particles` is a class for the background, while `ProjectSliderComponent` is the content of the main page. MySidebar is not shown; where can I look for the error? I'm confused

Comment: you are missing your state object in your component

Comment: @Kleo I've added this.state = {isOpen:true, disableCloseOnEsc:true} inside constructor, is this enough?

Comment: Sorry but we can't deduce your code. Please send an updated version of it. You are mentioning that your state is `isOpen` and `disableCloseOnEsc` and inside your `ProjectSliderComponent` you are using `this.state.projectList`. We can't assist you like that

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I've updated the code.

Comment: Look in the console window see if there's any errors

Comment: i just followed the tutorial, seems like you have to apply the css as well

Comment: Added but is not showing. I've tried deleting the Particles and ProjectSliderComponent from the render, and it is shown, but not with the properties set in the css file. Also, it is not always visible

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you here. You are posting partial components. You are initializing your constructor and your state object is nowhere to be found.